# How to implement a custom forward/backward function for torch.autograd.Function?

Tags: python, optimization, pytorch, gradient, autograd

I would like to use pytorch to optimize a objective function which makes use of an operation that cannot be tracked by torch.autograd.
I wrapped such operation with a custom forward() of the torch.autograd.Function class (as suggested [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/extending.html) and [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/autograd.html)). Since I know the gradient of such operation, i can write also the backward(). Everything look like this:

```
class Projector(torch.autograd.Function):

    # non_torch_var are constant values needed by the operation
    @staticmethod
    def forward(ctx, vertices, non_torch_var1, non_torch_var2, non_torch_var3):

        ctx.save_for_backward(vertices)
        vertices2=vertices.detach().cpu().numpy()
        ctx.non_torch_var1  = non_torch_var1 
        ctx.non_torch_var2  = non_torch_var2  
        ctx.non_torch_var3  = non_torch_var3 
        out = project_mesh(vertices2, non_torch_var1, non_torch_var2, non_torch_var3)
        out = torch.tensor(out, requires_grad=True)
        return out

    @staticmethod
    def backward(ctx, grad_out):
        vertices  = ctx.saved_tensors[0]
        vertices2 = vertices.detach().cpu().numpy()
        non_torch_var1 = ctx.non_torch_var1
        non_torch_var2 = ctx.non_torch_var2 
        non_torch_var3 = ctx.non_torch_var3

        grad_vertices = grad_project_mesh(vertices2, non_torch_var1, non_torch_var2, non_torch_var3)
        grad_vertices = torch.tensor(grad_vertices, requires_grad=True)
        return grad_vertices, None, None, None
```

This implementation, although, seems to not work. I used the torchviz package to plot what is going on with the following lines

```
import torchviz
out = Projector.apply(*input)
grad_x, = torch.autograd.grad(out.sum(), vertices, create_graph=True)
torchviz.make_dot((grad_x, vertices, out), params={"grad_x": grad_x, "vertices": vertices, "out": out}).render("attached", format="png")
```

and I got this [graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNAZb.png), which is showing that grad_x is not connected to anything.

Do you have an idea of what is going wrong with such a code?

Comment: In your plotting code, input == vertices right? Have you checked if the value of grad_x is correct? If it is, then the gradient does flow.

Comment: It is indeed true. Gradient is flowing, even if the graph generated by the torchviz package shows that the "grad_x" box standing by itself. Do you want to write it as answer?

Comment: Done. Please accept it if you think it's helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The graph correctly shows how `out` is computed from `vertices` (which seems to equal `input` in your code). Variable `grad_x` is correctly shown as disconnected because it isn't used to compute `out`. In other words, `out` isn't a function of `grad_x`. That `grad_x` is disconnected doesn't mean the gradient doesn't flow nor your custom `backward` implementation doesn't work. On the contrary, that a path exists from `vertices` to `out` in the graph means that the gradient should flow, i.e. the autograd engine can compute the gradient of `out` w.r.t `vertices`. To check the correctness of your custom `backward` implementation, you need to check if the value of `grad_x` is correct.

In short, the gradient should flow because there is a path from `vertices` to `out`, and its correctness should be verified by inspecting its values and not by looking at the computation graph.